# What function $f(x)$satisfies $\int{f(x)}dx=f(x)$ and how to prove it?

Tags: calculus

The answer may be $e^x$, but also $ne^x$. There must be a proof to know all those possible answers.

EDIT: I think the question might be wrong because you don't understand me. Let's change the question. How to prove that the only answer that satisfies $\int{f(x)}dx=f(x)$ is $f(x)=ne^x$?

Comment: $\omega^{\text {th}}$-plicate

Comment: If you already know $e^x$ is a solution, then $\int n e^x = n \int e^x = n e^x$

Comment: But there must be a way to prove all those answers.

Comment: @JBKing $f(x)=0$ is a particular case of $ne^x$ for $n=0$.

Comment: I think the OP always knows about $x\mapsto Ce^x$ and he wants to know how to prove that there are the **only** solutions.

Comment: Have you considered the power series expansion of $e^x$?  Proving the case for $n=1$ will allow you to use @DevenWare's method to prove the rest of the cases

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $e^x$ is a solution we know that $n e^x$ is also a solution, since

$$ \int n e^x = n \int e^x = n e^x$$

To see this is all the solutions, suppose $f$ satisfies this equation. Then $f'(x) = f(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. And then

$$ (fe^{-x})' = f' e^{-x} - f e^{-x} = 0 $$

hence $f e^{-x}$ is constant

Comment: You're assuming differentiability of $f$ here.

Comment: @Kris, I don't believe so. If $f$ is integrable, then $\int f$ is continuous, but $\int f = f$ so $f$ is continuous. But if $f$ is continuous then $\int f$ is differentiable with derivative $f$. and $\int f = f$ so $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: One obtains immediately from the usual definition of the *indefinite* integral that $f$ is differentiable with derivative $f$ (there is a slight abuse of notation here).

Answer (score 0):

If f is continuous, then you can use the FTC , so that $\frac{d}{dt}$ $\int_a^x f(t)dt$=$f(x)=f'(x)+C$ , where $C$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is integrable and $\int f(x)dx =f(x)$, then we have $\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)=\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$. But using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that means

$$f(x)=f'(x)$$

This is a separable differential equation whose solutions are all of the form $f(x)=Ce^x$.